# How to run the command ```sails run deploy``` on windows 10?

Tags: sails.js

I'm using sailsJS and I would like to deploy the app to Heroku, but I can't run the command `sails run deploy`.

```sh
'"echo 'This script assumes a dead-simple, opinionated setup on Heroku.' && echo 'But, of course, you can deploy your app anywhere you like.' && echo '(Node.js/Sails.js apps are supported on all modern hosting platforms.)' && echo && echo 'Warning: Specifically, this script assumes you are on the master branch, and that your app can be deployed simply by force-pushing on top of the *deploy* branch.  It will also temporarily use a local *predeploy* branch for preparing assets, that it will delete after it finishes.  Please make sure there is nothing you care about on either of these two branches!!!' && echo '' && echo '' && echo 'Preparing to deploy...' && echo '--' && git status && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'I hope you are on the master branch and have everything committed/pulled/pushed and are completely up to date and stuff.' && echo '********************************************'  && echo '** IF NOT THEN PLEASE PRESS <CTRL+C> NOW! **' && echo '********************************************' && echo 'Press CTRL+C to cancel.' && echo '(you have five seconds)' && sleep 1 && echo '...4' && sleep 1 && echo '...3' && sleep 1 && echo '...2' && sleep 1 && echo '...1' && sleep 1  && echo '' && echo 'Alright, here we go.  No turning back now!' && echo 'Trying to switch to master branch...' && git checkout master && echo && echo 'OK.  Now wiping node_modules/ and running npm install...' && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && (git add package-lock.json && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Did fresh npm install before deploying, and it caused something relevant (probably the package-lock.json file) to change!  This commit tracks that change.' || true) && echo 'Deploying as version:' && npm version patch && echo '' && git push origin master && git push --tags && (git branch -D predeploy > /dev/null 2>&1 || true) && git checkout -b predeploy && (echo 'Now building+minifying assets for production...' && echo '(Hang tight, this could take a while.)' && echo && node node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt buildProd || (echo && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo 'IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!' && echo 'ERROR: Could not compile assets for production!' && echo && echo 'Attempting to recover automatically by stashing, ' && echo 'switching back to the master branch, and then ' && echo 'deleting the predeploy branch... ' && echo && echo 'After this, please fix the issues logged above' && echo 'and push that up.  Then, try deploying again.' && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo && echo 'Staging, deleting the predeploy branch, and switching back to master...' && git stash && git checkout master && git branch -D predeploy && false)) && mv www .www && git add .www && node -e 'sailsrc = JSON.parse(require(\"fs\").readFileSync(\".' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

> Error occured running `echo 'This script assumes a dead-simple, opinionated setup on Heroku.' && echo 'But, of course, you can deploy your app anywhere you like.' && echo '(Node.js/Sails.js apps are supported on all modern hosting platforms.)' && echo && echo 'Warning: Specifically, this script assumes you are on the master branch, and that your app can be deployed simply by force-pushing on top of the *deploy* branch.  It will also temporarily use a local *predeploy* branch for preparing assets, that it will delete after it finishes.  Please make sure there is nothing you care about on either of these two branches!!!' && echo '' && echo '' && echo 'Preparing to deploy...' && echo '--' && git status && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'I hope you are on the master branch and have everything committed/pulled/pushed and are completely up to date and stuff.' && echo '********************************************'  && echo '** IF NOT THEN PLEASE PRESS <CTRL+C> NOW! **' && echo '********************************************' && echo 'Press CTRL+C to cancel.' && echo '(you have five seconds)' && sleep 1 && echo '...4' && sleep 1 && echo '...3' && sleep 1 && echo '...2' && sleep 1 && echo '...1' && sleep 1  && echo '' && echo 'Alright, here we go.  No turning back now!' && echo 'Trying to switch to master branch...' && git checkout master && echo && echo 'OK.  Now wiping node_modules/ and running npm install...' && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && (git add package-lock.json && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Did fresh npm install before deploying, and it caused something relevant (probably the package-lock.json file) to change!  This commit tracks that change.' || true) && echo 'Deploying as version:' && npm version patch && echo '' && git push origin master && git push --tags && (git branch -D predeploy > /dev/null 2>&1 || true) && git checkout -b predeploy && (echo 'Now building+minifying assets for production...' && echo '(Hang tight, this could take a while.)' && echo && node node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt buildProd || (echo && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo 'IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!' && echo 'ERROR: Could not compile assets for production!' && echo && echo 'Attempting to recover automatically by stashing, ' && echo 'switching back to the master branch, and then ' && echo 'deleting the predeploy branch... ' && echo && echo 'After this, please fix the issues logged above' && echo 'and push that up.  Then, try deploying again.' && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo && echo 'Staging, deleting the predeploy branch, and switching back to master...' && git stash && git checkout master && git branch -D predeploy && false)) && mv www .www && git add .www && node -e 'sailsrc = JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync("./.sailsrc", "utf8"));  if (sailsrc.paths&&sailsrc.paths.public !== undefined || sailsrc.hooks&&sailsrc.hooks.grunt !== undefined) { throw new Error("Cannot complete deployment script: .sailsrc file has conflicting contents!  Please throw away this midway-complete deployment, switch back to your original branch (master), remove the conflicting stuff from .sailsrc, then commit and push that up."); }  sailsrc.paths = sailsrc.paths || {};  sailsrc.paths.public = "./.www";   sailsrc.hooks = sailsrc.hooks || {};  sailsrc.hooks.grunt = false;  require("fs").writeFileSync("./.sailsrc", JSON.stringify(sailsrc))' && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Automatically bundling compiled assets as part of deploy, updating the EJS layout and .sailsrc file accordingly.' && git push origin predeploy && git checkout master && git push origin +predeploy:deploy && git push --tags && git branch -D predeploy && git push origin :predeploy && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'OK, done.  It should be live momentarily on your staging environment.' && echo '(if you get impatient, check the Heroku dashboard for status)' && echo && echo 'Staging environment:' && echo ' –•  https://staging.example.com' && echo '       (hold ⌘ and click to open links in the terminal)' && echo && echo 'Please review that to make sure it looks good.' && echo 'When you are ready to go to production, visit your pipeline on Heroku and press the PROMOTE TO PRODUCTION button.'`
>   Please resolve any issues and try `sails run deploy` again.
>   Details:
>   Error: Exit status 1
>       at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\hothv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails-run.js:358:26)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
>       at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
>       at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:597:12)

Comment: Im getting the same thing.